# Streaming audio in windows phone 7 app

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, stream, audio-streaming

If I do this in Javascript I can play the music streak behind the source url. No problem.

```
var music = new Audio();
var source = http://*HOST*.grooveshark.com/stream.php?streamKey=*STREAMKEY*;
music.src = source;
music.play();
```

Even better I can have a web control in my WP7 app that does this, and magically I have music playing in the app. However, I want to have audio int he background as well. So I can't just stream audio in a web browser control.

I need to take the above kind of audio source, but use it in a native Windows Phone app. There seems to be lots of ways, MediaElement, BackgroundAudioPlayer, etc., etc.... but none of them seem to work the the above url. I can pass them a link to an mp3 on a server somewhere and everything goes fine. But I can't seem to stream audio on a windows phone via a url like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try JavaScript way with Phonegap Media API for Windows Phone

[Cordova Media API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media)

and do it look like:

```
    my_media = new Media("test.mp3", onSuccess, onError);
    function onSuccess() {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
    }
    // onError Callback 
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: That's a very interesting idea... one of the reasons I'm going this path instead of just having a web control where I have a htmlaudioelement is I want to be able to play audio in the background... does the Phonegab framework support this, on windows phone?